# What is the limit of $\prod\limits_{i=2}^n\frac{2i^2-i-1}{2i^2+i-1}$ when $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, products, infinite-product

What is the value of $$\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{2i^2-i-1}{2i^2+i-1}$$ when $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: Two questions posted, with 0 and 0 context. Any more to come?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{2i^2-i-1}{2i^2+i-1}=\frac{(2i+1)(i-1)}{(2i-1)(i+1)}.$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}\prod_{i=2}^n\frac{2i^2-i-1}{2i^2+i-1}&=\frac{\prod_{i=2}^n(2i+1)}{\prod_{i=2}^n(2i-1)}\cdot
\frac{\prod_{i=2}^n(i-1)}{\prod_{i=2}^n(i+1)}
\\&=\frac{\prod_{i=2}^n(2i+1)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(2i+1)}\cdot
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}i}{\prod_{i=3}^{n+1}i}
=\frac{2n+1}{3}\cdot\frac{1\cdot 2}{n(n+1)}.
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!